# how to alert message to the screen when user with email and password is created successful in firebase web using javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function createUser(email,password){

  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {

    //Handle errors here
   alert("User authentication failed!");

  // ...
});
}
```

Here is my function that creates user with email and password, so i want to alert a message when user is created successful just like i can alert a message "User authentication failed" when the user is not created successfully.

Comment: What does the function createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password) return? Is it a promise or another object?

Comment: Attach a `.then` maybe?

Comment: Like @JonasWilms said, before .catch() add .then()

Comment: Thanks it worked for me!